# ball moves however only once

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics, keylistener

I am creating a program that creates a ball that will be moved using arrow keys however when i run the code then the ball start's in the corner and i can only move it once in every direction.
Here's the code:

```
package squareMovingUsingArrowKeys;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class squareMovingUsingArrowKeys extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {
static int x;
static int y;
Timer timer;
squareMovingUsingArrowKeys() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    timer = new Timer(20, this);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        x = -1;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        x = 1;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        y = -1;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        y = 1;
    }

    //first call move to update x and y and later repaint that JPanel
    move(x, y);
    repaint();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
}
public void start() {
    keyPressed(null);
    paintComponent(null);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Moving");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    squareMovingUsingArrowKeys m = new squareMovingUsingArrowKeys();
    f.add(m);
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    m.timer.start();
    f.addKeyListener(m);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is not homework or anything like that i am just learning java and want to try it.
please also remember that i am only 9 years old and a noob.

Comment: Quick solution: make the JPanel that has the KeyListener focusable and then give it the focus. Better and more robust solution: use Key Bindings and not a KeyListener. [Search for similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=swing+keylistener+jpanel+focus&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&oq=swing+keylistener+jpanel+focus&aqs=chrome..69i57.5560j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=swing+keylistener+jpanel+focus+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it only moves once is that in your key listener you are directly assigning `x` and `y` to ± 1 instead of adjusting the previous value. To modify the previous value you need to do `x = x + 1;` or `x += 1;` or `x++;` or equivalent. E.g.:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    x -= 1;
} 
else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
    x += 1;
}
else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
    y -= 1;
}
else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
    y += 1;
}
```

Some other problems I see in your code:

- Convention is that classes (like `squareMovingUsingArrowKeys`) should be named beginning with a capital letter.
- `x` and `y` should not be `static` here, since that would share the variables between multiple instances of the class, instead of letting each instance have its own position.
- You should not call `move`. That moves the entire `JPanel`, but the `JPanel` is already drawing the ball moved relative to itself, so that is all you need. You do not need `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` either. If you do want to move the `JPanel` without the deprecation warning, call `setLocation` instead (the `move` method was renamed in Java 1.1, and that is what the warning is about).
- The way in which key events are sent by the system is causing some problems. When you hold down a key the ball will move once immediately but have a small delay before it begins to move repeatedly. This is due to the key repeat delay you get when you hold down any key. It's correct for typing but looks wrong for game object movement. Worse, its rate can be system dependent, so the ball will not move at a consistent speed on different systems. Also, moving diagonally is not working; it seems that press events for a key are not sent when a second key is simultaneously pressed. A way to fix all these problems is to use the key events not to adjust the ball position directly, but to update state variables saying which keys are currently held down. Then, implement the actual update of `x` and `y` in your `Timer`'s `ActionListener`:

  ```
  private boolean movingLeft, movingRight, movingUp, movingDown;

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
          movingLeft = true;
      } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
          movingRight = true;
      } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
          movingUp = true;
      } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
          movingDown = true;
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
          movingLeft = false;
      } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
          movingRight = false;
      } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
          movingUp = false;
      } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
          movingDown = false;
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (movingLeft) x -= 1;
      if (movingRight) x += 1;
      if (movingUp) y -= 1;
      if (movingDown) y += 1;
      repaint();
  }

  /* ... rest of the code the same ... */
  ```
- All interaction with Swing is supposed to happen on a dedicated thread called the Event Dispatch Thread. [In `main` you should call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) to move to the correct thread:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
          JFrame f = new JFrame("Moving");
          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          /* ... rest of code for setting up frame here ... */
      });
  }
  ```

  The use of the wrong thread to interact with Swing is not currently causing a problem in your program, but it is still technically incorrect, and it's the sort of thing that could potentially cause subtle problems down the line. The rest of your program is event-driven so it is already running on the correct thread.

Good luck!

Comment: I would have preferred just ifs for the 1st part, because then it can move diagonally.

Comment: @bleh It can and does move diagonally. Pressing two keys sends two keyPress events with separate key codes.